# Когда говорят двое - диалог, а если больше?

Tags: пунктуация

Всегда считал, что диалогом в грамматике называется любой разговор героев - все зависит от пунктуационного оформления. Мол, прямая речь, это, когда в кавычках, а диалог, когда каждое предложение с новой строки и начинает с тире. Но потом мне попалась вот эта картинка:

[image]

То есть, если разговаривают больше двух, это уже не диалог, а полилог? Или в грамматике все равно называется диалогом?

Comment: *Диалог - разговор двух или более лиц.*
*Полилог - разговор многих людей*. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > Или в грамматике все равно называется диалогом?

Грамматика ни при чем. Это общеязыковое понятие.
Да, когда больше двух, это все равно диалог. 
Тут смысл в том что говорит один, а другой (другие) слушают. Потом отвечают.

Можно назвать и полилогом, если собеседников трое или больше. Но это менее употребительно во всех отношениях.

Answer (score 3):

Диалогом условились называть разговор двух и более лиц. [Извольте убедиться](http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=диалог&from=ru&to=xx&submitFormSearch=Найти&stype=0). Существованию термина "полилог" это не мешает. 
Диалог может записываться как без кавычек через тире, так и с кавычками. Убедиться в этом Вы можете, ознакомившись с  [§123. Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm#з_05) Справочника по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию Розенталя.